# How to execute WMLscripts and WML codes?

Tags: debugging, nokia, sample, wml

i've downloaded the Nokia Mobile Internet Toolkit and tried to execute couple of sample WML codes but itz not executing? Can any one guide me how to start with wml development as i am beginner to this?

Comment: you'll need to make your question much more precise. please post the exact steps you've taken, the exact error messages you're seeing, etc...

Comment: Anyway, do you know that WAP is an almost dead technology?

Comment: Agree, try starting with basic html development.

Answer (score 0):

Use a tester service:

- [Wap Control](http://wap-control.sourceforge.net/)
- [WML Browser](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/wmlbrowser/)
- [CGI::WML](http://cgi-wml.sourceforge.net/)